# Multiple Regression in Math.Net Numerics

Tags: c#, linear-regression, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I achieved simple single regression using math.net regression method like this:

```
var xdata = new double[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
var ydata = new double[] { 15, 20, 25, 55, 95 }; 

var X = DenseMatrix.CreateFromColumns(new[] { new DenseVector(xdata.Length, 1), new DenseVector(xdata) });
var y = new DenseVector(ydata);

var p = X.QR().Solve(y);
var a = p[0];
var b = p[1];

MessageBox.Show(a.ToString(), "Test");
MessageBox.Show(b.ToString(), "Test");
```

Question is: What can I apply multiple regression with this method? So, I have also `zdata` array and I want to use this for multiple regression.

Answer (score 1):

This form, as introduced in [Linear Regression With Math.NET Numerics](http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/2012/9/9/linear-regression-mathnet-numerics.html), is technically already a multiple linear regression.

Assuming you have data points `((uj,vj),yj)` instead of `(xj,yj)`, you can map `x` to the tuple `u,v` accordingly when building the X matrix. So the cell `X[i,j]` would then instead of `fi(xj)` be evaluated as `fi(uj,vj)`.

For example, for a linear regression to a spatial line given by `y=a+b*u+c*v`, you would end up with:

- `p1 = a`, `f1 : u,v -> 1`
- `p2 = b`, `f2 : u,v -> u`
- `p3 = c`, `f3 : u,v -> v`

Hence the full system:

```
|y1|   |1  u1  v1|   |a|
|y2| = |1  u2  v2| * |b|
|..|   |.. ..  ..|   |c|
|yM|   |1  uM  vM|
```

Please leave a comment if it is unclear how this would work in actual code, or not what you're looking for.

Comment: Christoph, could you help with a few lines of C# code? I think I understand the concept here is xj is not a scalar but a vector itself (tuple as you wrote), but I can not figure out how the actual preparing the input data will be. Thx

Comment: Sure. Can you pick a target function I should use in the sample code? Maybe something like `y: (u,v) -> a+b*sin(u)+c*cos(v)`?

Comment: Christoph, thx for the feedback. Meanwhile I've managed to solve the multiple case, I have to say Math.NET is cool!.

Answer (score 1):

@christoph-ruegg Thank you for your post on Linear Regression, that helped me to get started with Math.NET.
@team16sah @g-pickardou If you have access to the Math.NET library, I suggest you use the [Fit.Polynomial()](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Fit.htm) method. I found it more reliable and flexible than just using the Linear Regression.
In your case above, the code would look like:

```
        var xdata = new double[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
        var ydata = new double[] { 15, 20, 25, 55, 95 };

        double[] p = Fit.Polynomial(xdata, ydata, 1);
        var a = p[0];
        var b = p[1];

        MessageBox.Show(a.ToString(), "Test");
        MessageBox.Show(b.ToString(), "Test");
```

Then you can change the polynomial order (third parameter of the Polynomial function) to get more precision.